# Intent Activity Refreshes Instead of Opening New Activity Upon Button Click

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-activity

I am making a small app which uses multiple screens which all link together using declaration of "android:onClick=" in XML and an intent statement in the Java source code. All of them work apart from the one in the login screen. Whenever I press the Continue button all it does is it bring up the same activity up, just like it were refreshing itself.

I have tried literally everything, and it makes me question whether the Facebook button functionality code has anything to do with it...?

Button in Login Activity XML code:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/loginOptionButton"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded_button"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:onClick="loginButton_onClick"/>
```

Login Screen Java Class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebookButton);

        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                goMainScreen();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.com_facebook_loginview_cancel_action, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.com_facebook_internet_permission_error_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT). show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void goMainScreen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void loginButton_onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

[image: Login Activity Screen]

MainActivity Java Class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle (this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
            goLoginScreen();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true ;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void goLoginScreen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void logout(View view) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        goLoginScreen();
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Post the code of your MainActivity, please.

Comment: @MateusGondim Why is the code for my MainActivity relevant?

Comment: it's the screen supposed to be opened when you click the button

Comment: @MateusGondim True, it's uploaded now. But typically nothing needs adding to the child activity's code in order for it to work. Maybe something in there is causing it to block the onClickListener... Take a look.

Comment: it seems like `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` is returning null, which is causing the app to return to login screen.

Comment: @MateusGondim I see. In this case, what should it be change to in order to work properly?

Comment: It really depends on your requirements, like what the app should do when the token is null. I'd start investigating why that method is returning null.

Comment: Well my requirements are for the button to be able to navigate to the MainActivity screen. So what should I change the token value to? Also, how will changing this affect the Facebook button, if at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to make an answer because i can not comment unfortunately.

is this null?

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
        goLoginScreen();
    }
```

if so it'll just send you back to your login screen.

Comment: No worries. Ok, then what should I do with this expression?

Comment: Have you tested to see if that is your current problem?

Comment: I believe that's the problem yeah. What should the value be if not null?

Comment: I personally don't know much about AccessToken and what you need it to do. But the purpose of checking if it's null is to prevent a NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION later on in the program for when you do use it. My recommendation to you is learn more about what it is used for and why it's null for you. Maybe it's null if the user does not log on via face book. So before checking if the accesstoken is null first check if the user is trying to log on via facebook.